# Bootstrap - change form fields according to selected item from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a form build on Bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="topic">What can we help you with ?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="topic">
          <option value="Work with us">I want to know more about your services</option>
          <option value="Request a demo">I want a no-obligation demo of your services</option>
          <option value="Employment query">I am interested in working for you</option>
     </select>
</div>
....
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="time_callback">* What time should we call you back ?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="time_callback">
         <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
         <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
         <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
    </select>
</div>
------------
// replace with "time_callback"
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="send_cv">* Upload your CV</label>
            <input type="file" name="send_cv" />
        </div>
```

By default the form has the 2 dropdowns, but when I pick from `"topic"` the `"Employment query"` I want to replace the `"send_cv"` (upload input) with the  `"time_callback"` (2nd dropdown), so basically it will give the idea of having two different forms.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/auhnd2cx/)**

Add class `callback` and `upload` to their respective parent divs as shown below:

```
<div class="form-group callback"> <!--Add here-->
    <label for="time_callback">* What time should we call you back ?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="time_callback">
         <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
         <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
         <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group upload"><!--and here-->
       <label for="send_cv">* Upload your CV</label>
       <input type="file" name="send_cv" />
</div>
```

Hide `callback` div at first

```
.callback{
   display:none;
}
```

Write `on change` event for your `select`

```
$('select[name="topic"]').on('change',function(){
   if($(this).val()=="Employment query")
   {
        $('.upload').hide();
        $('.callback').show();
   }
   else
   {
        $('.upload').show();
        $('.callback').hide();
   }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can do as below with `switch case`

```
$('select[name="topic"]').on('change',function(){
   var selectedVal=$(this).val();
   switch(selectedVal){
       case 'Employment query':
                   $('.upload').hide();
                   $('.callback').show();
             break;
       case 'some more cases':case 'one more case': 
       //Add this into consideration if you have multiple cases where functionality has to be same
                   $('.upload').show();
                   $('.callback').hide();
             break;
       default: //change this according to your need
                   $('.upload').show();
                   $('.callback').hide();
             break;
   }
});
```

Comment: Can I also do it using a switch-case statement when picking a `topic` if I have many types like this, and if so how it could be done? sorry for asking again, but I'm not good in javascript

Comment: Yes what I mean is something like this: if the 1st topic is selected -> show these x fields, if 2nd topic is selected show y fields and if the 3rd is selected show z fields (like the upload)

Comment: One more question please.. in case of the form validation fails, how I can make sure that my form won't return to the default statement? for example if I have an error on the upload field, how can I keep the upload field if validation fails? btw: Im using php -codeigniter for server side

Comment: For that I might need to see the way you are doing `form` validation!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery change function to make the divs visible or not

e.g.

```
$("#topic").change(function() {
    if ($("#topic").val() == "Employment query") {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").show();
    } 
 }
```

Don't forget you would need to put id='div1' and also id='div2' on the appropriate div's

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code,

```js
$("#selecttopic").change(function(){
      var selectedVal = $("#selecttopic option:selected").val();
      if(selectedVal == "Employment query"){
          $("#divsendcv").show();
          $("#divcallback").hide();
        
        }else{
          $("#divsendcv").hide();
          $("#divcallback").show();
          }
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="topic">What can we help you with ?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="topic" id="selecttopic">
          <option value="Work with us">I want to know more about your services</option>
          <option value="Request a demo">I want a no-obligation demo of your services</option>
          <option value="Employment query">I am interested in working for you</option>
     </select>
</div>
....
<div class="form-group" id="divcallback">
    <label for="time_callback">* What time should we call you back ?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="time_callback">
         <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
         <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
         <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
    </select>
</div>
------------
// replace with "time_callback"
    <div class="form-group" id="divsendcv" style="display:none;">
            <label for="send_cv">* Upload your CV</label>
            <input type="file" name="send_cv" />
        </div>
```

Let me know if you have any problem with this